# How do I set my screen resolution on Fedora 32 XFCE4?

Tags: fedora, x11, xorg, xfce, display-settings

I recently upgraded one of my machines from Fedora 28 (I think) to FC32 with XFCE4.
After the update, my screen resolution is degraded to 640 x 480. Many items do not work at such a low resolution, because buttons falls outside the screen.

When I tried to change the Display Settings, the only selection for the resolution is 640x480.

There is no xorg.conf file that I can edit.

There is no "system-config-display" that I can use to generate one.

When I try to generate it by typing "Xorg -configure" I am told tht I must stop the X server first, but when I kill it, it respawns.

How do I resolve this? This works on my other Fedora systems ... just not this one.

Comment: what does `xrandr -q` say? If your system supports more than the resolution above, I might have a solution. But it could be that wayland is running... then xrandr won't work

Comment: "xrandr -q" says "Can't open display".

Comment: I did eventually figure out to stop the X server and the XFCE login screen by entering
"init 3", allowing me to create an xorg.conf file.

Comment: Now that I have tried to fill in all the missing fields in that template xorg.conf file (and moving it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf) it fails to run.

/var/log/Xorg.0.log says (among many other things)
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section
(EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.

How do I find out what devices it had detected?

Comment: Okay, so after I delete xorg.conf and start with all the default options, "xrandr -q" says:

Screen 0 minimum 640x480, current 640x480, maximum 640x480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    640x480     0.00*

That does not tell me anything I did not already know.

Comment: The monitor supports 1680x1050.
I cannot imagine the video adapter not supporting 800x600 or 1024x780

Comment: if `xrandr -q` answers  `can't open display` then you did not install the proper driver for your GPU - whatever that is. `lspci | grep VGA ` would shed some light on it

Comment: 4 months later, we are at FC34 and the problem persists.

Comment: [root@Chameleon ~]# lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your monitor supports more than 640x800, but the Xserver does not know the Monitor -obviously is does not sent you any EDID data, that the X-Server needs.
In order to get a valid resolution you need to setup a conf file:

`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-monitor.conf`

At least this is the  place, where I've put my config files. Since I do not know what hardware you have,I'd suggest to install `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `libdrm-intel1` (reading the error concerning `dri`). I wonder what you put into your conf file. I assume you configured the "device" section, but it looks the "Monitor" Section must be setup...

Maybe you could share the contents of your conf file... by adding it to your question

Comment: As I explained to begin with, there was no xorg.conf file
The one generated by "Xorg -configure" had a video device "Card0" but when xorg started, it said there is no /dev/dri/card0 - which is true.

My efforts have been trying to figure out what I could possibly put in the Display section, to define the video chip/card. The system in question is a SuperMicro rackmount server, and I think the Xorg server is using it in "generic quasi-VGA mode".
The two packages you suggest do not exist on Fedora 32. I do, however, have packages named libdrm and xorg-x11-drivers-intel.

Comment: Yes, you said so. But was wondering, what these "missing fields in that template xorg.conf file.." looked like. Usually there is no Xorg conf file in modern distros, but you always have the option to add one. I had to do it to get my nvidia card running. You did not mention what graphics you have (which would have helped) but I assumed you have an intel GPU.. Could you add the log in `/var/log/Xorg0.log` to your question?

Comment: The hardware is an ASPEED (ast) chip. The kernel seems to contain an ast driver, but I do not know how to get the system to load that instead of the "modesetting"driver, which I believe is a generic VGA driver - which should be okay, also.

Comment: I cannot write a Device section for xorg.conf, because the kernel has not created a /dev/xxx device for the GPU. I cannot write a Screen section, because it is mandatory that it must point to a Device section.

Comment: ASPEED provides a driver kit with RPMS but they are only for specific RHEL releases, and even the SRPMS are specific to those releases.

Comment: I would like to write a 20-monitor.conf for the monitor, but I do not have an example to go by.

Comment: I think I will just have to run the system in "init 3" mode instead of XFCE.
I guess that is what I get for trying to use a 10-year-old rack server.
Funny, though, my other rack server, which is a lowly 32-bit Intel Atom chip, works just fine out of the box.

Comment: I doubt that ASPEED is a CPU- it its service module chip for servers. Question is, what kind of GPU do you have. Output of  `lspci` would help (and add it to your question)

Comment: [root@Chameleon ~]# lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 30)